# Is there a genetic link between North America and Vikings?

Tags: native-americans, vikings

Is there any evidence of Viking genetics in the North East American Indian population? There is a blue eye trait in some East Coast tribes, especially the Iroquoian tribe of the Cherokee.

Comment: Can we get a reference for that blue-eyed Cherokee claim? (If its Elisabeth Warren, I'm gonna be mad...)

Comment: I found some fascinating [stuff](http://mysteriousuniverse.org/2017/10/the-mysterious-tribe-of-blue-eyed-native-americans/) about the blue eyed Mandan...

Comment: @justCal - Interesting indeed, but their language is (yes **IS**, there are still Mandan around) Siouxan, which makes sense given where they were living. This is why we could really use a link to exactly what is being talked about. There's a good chance I could answer this if I knew that.

Comment: @T.E.D.  I found more strangeness [here](https://www.accessgenealogy.com/native/cherokee-dna.htm). I would like your take on this middle-east connection, I had not seen this before.

Comment: ...and FWIW, the pics in that article showing these supposed European-looking Mandan to my eyes have a much more distinct resemblance to my Osage relatives (Osage are also Siouan)

Comment: @justCal - Ask that as a question and I might find the time to look into it. I did read over the article, and I'll say its not drawing the same conclusions from the data its presenting that I would.

Comment: Just for the record, this is an older question (circa 2017); currently we'd expect any question about genetics to be supported by stronger preliminary research. There is an unfortunate but strong correlation between questions about genetics, push questions and troll-bait.

Answer (score 18):

I am going to say Yes, to the title question, and No to the question in the body.

**Is there a link...**

There *is a genetic link*, but not in the direction you were expecting.  An [article published](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2010/11/101123-native-american-indian-vikings-iceland-genetic-dna-science-europe/) on the National Geographic website makes some claims concerning Native American DNA signatures located among Icelandic populations:

> Analyzing a type of DNA passed only from mother to child, scientists
>   found more than 80 living Icelanders with a genetic variation similar
>   to one found mostly in Native Americans.

and

> "We know that Vikings sailed to the Americas," said Agnar Helgason of
>   deCODE Genetics and the University of Iceland, who co-wrote the study
>   with his student Sigrídur Ebenesersdóttir and colleagues. "So all you
>   have to do is assume … that they met some people and ended up taking
>   at least one female back with them.

but

> Despite the evidence, for now it's nearly impossible to prove a
>   direct, thousand-year-old genetic link between Native Americans and
>   Icelanders.
>
> For starters, no living Native American group carries the exact
>   genetic variation found in the Icelandic families.

In light of another answer mentioning Greenland, the DNA study looked at that as well:

> The [Inuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuit), often called Eskimos, *carry no version of the variant*—a
>   crucial detail, given that Greenland has a native Inuit population

So this DNA sample cannot be traced to any interaction with the Inuit.

.

---

This leads us to the more specific query implied in the body of the question, essentially :
**Were there blue-eyed Cherokee Native Americans descended from Vikings?**

One problem with this is that technically we don't even seem to know what Cherokee DNA looks like to start wth. From a genealogy site, [AccessGenealogy](https://www.accessgenealogy.com/native/cherokee-dna.htm):

> First, the readers should understand that if any commercial DNA lab
>   returns tests results that state a percentage of DNA for a particular
>   Southeastern Native American tribe, the report should be considered
>   fraudulent. The American Society of Human Genetics has not certified
>   any DNA test markers to be associated with a particular Southeastern
>   American Indian tribe.

We don't have good DNA samples of any original,pre-colonial era North American Native American group so that we can isolate specific markers of that group. So to isolate Viking DNA parts in *modern* DNA, it would be very difficult to prove they were from original contact (abt. the year 1000) or later European contact during or after the colonial period.

Another website provides more discussion of the 'blue-eyed' issue here:[Native Languages.org](http://www.native-languages.org/iaq10.htm)

Comment: Upvoted for the NA -> Iceland angle, which hadn't occurred to me, but makes more sense knowing what we know about how genes move around. The stuff under the bar is also correct (although it remains to be seen exactly what "blue-eyed" genes issue the OP is referring to). However, I'd also add that Native Americans didn't *care* about "blood" like Europeans do. One of their Cheifs on the Trail of Tears was 3/4th Scots by "blood".

Comment: The Icelanders were also very isolated, so they make a good DNA source to work from. As to the Cherokee DNA stuff, yes direct citation of the 'source' of that aspect of the story would be beneficial. But even for a colonial to observe someone with blue-eyes in the 1600's, it would still be 600 years after any possible mixing...pretty thin

Comment: Weren't there a good many American soldiers stationed in Iceland during and after WWII?  Since a considerable portion of Americans have some Indian ancestry, all it takes is a few of them recreating off-base to mix up the gene pool.  How would you distinguish this from similar admixtures that happened more than 500 years ago?

Comment: @jamesqf  I'm no genetics expert, but the article mentions tracking this back into the 1700's. A relationship as recent as ww2 would be obvious in family histories. Part of the DNA stuff requires a good bit of genealogical research as well.

Comment: @jamesqf: It is also possible to estimate how long any specific marker has been in a population by how widely dispersed it is. Any (and **every**) single marker that has obtained dispersion through the Icelandic gene pool is far older than World War 2.

Comment: @justCal: WRT geneaology, I refer you to Homer.  "It's a wise child who knows its own father."

Comment: If you find the same rare genetic marker in several people who claim to have a common ancestor, the simplest assumption is that they are correct.

Comment: The Inuit are not the original Greenlanders (from the perspective of the Norse arriving about 1000 CE. -The Thule, ancestors of today's Inuit, arrived in Greenland, from the north, roughly when the Norse were abandoning it, circa 1400 CE. [Inuit History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenlandic_Inuit#History)

Answer (score 6):

Well, we never did get a reference for what "blue-eyed Cherokee"s you were actually talking about. However, the very first link I got on a google search happens to be a nice [Native American urban myth debunking page](http://www.native-languages.org/iaq10.htm) that I've directed people to before, so I'll quote the appropriate passage from it for you:

> Q: I heard that there was a tribe called the "blue-eyed Indians"
> because Norse or Celtic explorers intermarried with them. Is that
> true?
>
> A: No. There is no tribe of Indians that is predominantly
> blue-eyed. In fact, blue eyes, like blond hair, is genetically
> recessive, so if a full-blood Indian and a blue-eyed Caucasian person
> had a baby, it would be genetically impossible for that baby to have
> blue eyes. Blue eyes only occur in people who have blue-eyed Caucasian
> relatives on both sides of their family tree, and even then only some
> of the time. There are tribes who have had plenty of blue-eyed
> individuals after colonization, such as the Lumbees and the *Cherokees*,
> because those tribes lived in close contact with a Caucasian community
> as large as their own and intermarried with them frequently. Before
> colonization, not a chance. A few Norse or Celtic explorers couldn't
> have left behind blue-eyed Indian babies any more than a few
> Caucasians exploring Africa could have left behind a race of
> blond-haired black people.

For the Cherokee in fact probably their most historic Chief, [John Ross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Ross_(Cherokee_chief)), who led them through the Trail of Tears, was blue-eyed (and possibly red-haired). How did this happen you might ask? Well his father and his maternal Grandmother were both Scottish. Native Americans prior to cultural assimilation didn't have the European concept of "blood". Instead they were clan-based (likely why they got on well with the Scots), which was more of a voluntary association. Sort of like how Europeans are with their football teams.

Comment: I looked at this a little more tonight and did find some sites that tried connecting this to Roanoke as well.

Comment: The site oversimplifies the inheritance pattern for eye color.  It's correct that a full-blood Indian and a blue-eyed Viking can't have a blue-eyed baby, but if a number of Vikings and Indians interbreed, the *grandchildren* can have blue eyes.  A few Norse or Celtic explorers can't leave behind a tribe of blue-eyed Indians, but in the absence of selective pressure, they *can* leave behind a legacy of scattered blue-eyed individuals.  (This is ignoring the fact that eye color isn't a simple dominant/recessive inheritance pattern.)

Answer (score 0):

Norsemen traded with the Thule of the Arctic region, whom they called Scraelings. The Thule (Proto-Inuits) arrived in the northeast Atlantic zone not long after the Norse settled in Greenland. There was a paleolithic, pre-Thule population in the Atlantic region, called the Dorset culture. They were annihilated by the Thule. The Thule also prevented the Norse from permanently settling any further West than eastern Greenland. Ultimately, they drove the norse entirely out of Greenland, so there  were no Norsemen in the Americas. (Greenland is considered to be North America.) This left the Thule as the sold inhabitants of the Arctic zone.

The Thule came from the Bering Strait. The region was connected with Asian trade, and utilized iron. There was a lot of competition and warfare based around hunting grounds for the bow-headed whale. They had Mongolian bows and Chinese style slat armor, which they made from bone.  This made them militarily superior to the Norse. [Recent research](http://www.cbc.ca/natureofthings/features/history-of-the-thule-migration) suggests that Thule migrated from the Bering Strait to the Atlantic because Genghis Khan disrupted the iron trade from Asia.  Searching for new sources, they crossed to the continent with dog sleds in under 5 years.

Norsemen couldn't have taken Thule women as they pleased. I think that such interaction would probably have been in the form of kidnapping or trade, so the natives would be assimilated into the Norse. If they did have sexual interactions with the Dorset people, it wouldn't have mattered because they were decimated. There were other types of natives in Newfoundland and Labrador, and a few Norsemen reached here. Given the paucity of Norse archaeological sites, or archaeological evidence thereof, its hard to imagine any significant interactions with anyone outside of Greenland.

[image]

Comment: Useful background information - but I don't see an actual answer yet. Is that perhaps *still in progress*?

Comment: I don't think that I'll put more work into this question.

Comment: Fair enough. I might come back and top this off for you. This is a good base.

Comment: Sure. Something else that occured to me last night was if the Thule took or received Norse women. This comes down to the culture of Scandinavians in regards to women, and the possibility of Thule raids. I think the latter may  not have been likely if the Thule only had an distance advantage with the Mongolian bow. Rather than outright warfare, the territories could have been mostly determined by perceived pressures and mutual understanding.

Answer (score -1):

The term "blue eyes" is a misnomer. This refers to the appearance of light eyes in the tribes: a dark grey or green, most prevalent among the Mandans. It's re-appearance in some of the Snowbird Cherokee, is most likely due to later inter-breeding (aka: after the Trail of Tears). However, in the Algonquin legends it is well supported that the Norse did, indeed, interbreed with the Native groups. There existed no dissuading considerations for this. The Norse produced larger and hardier offspring.  Offspring that were always viewed as members of their tribe and clan.  Hardier offspring were considered a boon. Higher reproduction rates were a distinct advantage. Merely the broader hip span produced by the introduction of Western European lineage into the tribes, insured more successful births to the generations which followed this initial cross-fertilization.

Comment: This badly needs reputable sources to support its assertions. Do you have any?

Comment: @CyMadison please move that into the answer.

Comment: No - just edit the answer to include the citation; then we'll delete all the comments & the mod notice.  I did a quick search and I couldn't find that reference or I would have done it myself.  (but it is better if a non-moderator does it).

Comment: Just delete everything.